# Calculating and formatting time difference from PHP timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, math, timestamp

The banning system for my community website logs the times in the MySQL table with a timestamp.

I have got the following code to display the time the temporary ban was issued, but have not been able to work out the time difference. The way it logs the ban is it logs the time the ban was issued, and also logs the time that the temporary ban will finish. From this the length of the ban can be calculated, somehow...

```
<b>Time of ban:</b> <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $row['time']);?><br />
<b>Time of unban:</b> <?php echo $row['temptime'];?><br />
<b>Unban time - ban time=</b> <?php echo $diff;?>
```

When I try this:

```
<b>Tempban length:</b> <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $diff);?>
```

It outputs `Tempban length: 08/01/1970 01:00:00`

Please, someone show me where I am going wrong with this. Many thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to be setting `$diff` anywhere

Comment: Where/how is `$diff` being calculated/set?

Comment: Time difference is not a date . Then what `<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $diff);?>` really means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
//time when the person was banned
$banTime =  date_format($row['time'], 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // too make sure its the right format
$banLifted = date_format($row['temptime'], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$bt = new Datetime($banTime);
$bl = new Datetime($banLifted);

$diffTime = $bl->diff($bt);
```

Can you see if that serves your purpose..

you can always call:

```
$diffTime ->format('%R%a days'); //for number or days
```

Check this for more info [datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Dins

Comment: Your method is better and shortly, but **only from 5.3**

Answer (score 1):

```
$diff = $row['temptime'] - $row['time'];

$diff_years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$diff_monthes  = floor(($diff - $diff_years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$diff_days    = floor(($diff - $diff_years * 365*60*60*24 - $diff_monthes*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

$diff_hours   = floor(($diff - $diff_years * 365*60*60*24 - $diff_monthes*30*60*60*24 - $diff_days*60*60*24)/ (60*60));
$diff_minutes  = floor(($diff - $diff_years * 365*60*60*24 - $diff_monthes*30*60*60*24 - $diff_days*60*60*24 - $diff_hours*60*60)/ 60);

// here you can format output, using variables above, for example:
$diff = $diff_hours." hours, ".$diff_minutes." minutes.";

<b>Tempban length:</b> <?php echo $diff;?>
```

Comment: Serious? Calculating timestamp differences?

Comment: @dbf, what is no serious here? I have used this method a lot and it works great

Comment: @Ozerich you've just managed to make a 135 chars long line. A bit too long?

Comment: @Ozerich I think to use `$months` is always a bad idea as they aren't everythime 30 days.

Comment: @bwoebi, thanks for find bug. I have used this function in release project, now i have to remake this function

Comment: @Ozerich Simple, just use `date()`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't being wrong. date() works with seconds since `1/1/1970 00:00:00`. So when you have `86400*8 + 3600*1` seconds as diff, you'll have the `08/01/1970 01:00:00` as output. Also you'll have a diffence which corresponds to your timezone.

You have to use your own function to show time:

(`$seconds` is what in your code is called `$diff`)

```
$years = floor($seconds / 365 * 86400);
$days = floor(($seconds -= $years * 365 * 86400) / 86400);
$hours = floor(($seconds -= $days * 86400) / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($seconds -= $hours * 3600) / 60);
$seconds -= $minutes * 60;
echo "$years years, $days days, $hours hours, $minutes minutes and $seconds seconds";
```

Comment: @JamesAllison What's the output?

Answer (score 0):

`($row['temptime'] -$row['time'] )/60` gives you difference in `minute`

Answer (score 0):

I Think best way is

- $diff = strtotime('2009-10-05 18:11:08') - strtotime('2009-10-05 18:07:13')